# If statements in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, if-statement

I want to check if file.txt exists.
If it exists delete it and reinstall it.
If it does not exist download it.

```
Test-Path -Path file.txt -PathType Leaf
Remove-Item 'file.txt'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/file.txt -OutFile file.txt
```

I can't seem to figure out how to put this into an if statement (I am new to Powershell).

Comment: You may start with reading the help [about_If](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: With the help of the documentation provided by Olaf, you would just need to wrap the `Test-Path` statement in the conditional expression (`<test1>` from the doc) and the rest of the code would be within the curly braces (`<statement list 1>` from the doc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Test-Path -Path file.txt -PathType Leaf){
    Remove-Item file.txt
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/file.txt -OutFile file.txt
}
else{
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/file.txt -OutFile file.txt
}
```